# Sublime Text - How to Make "Quick Add Next" NOT wrap around the beginning of the file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The functionality "Quick Add Next" is handy, however there is one problem, that after it reaches the last match in the file, if I do it again, it will go on to include the first match in the file also (wrap), which is not what I want, because it's usually hard to realize whether you've reached the last match or not. This occurs even if the option "wrap" is disabled among search options. Is there anyway to disable it?

If no, is there a way to *unselect* the match I just added by "quick add next"? That would be a valid alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Quick Add Next* has the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on Windows/Linux. If you want to skip a selection, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) - meaning, hold down the <kbd>⌘</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) key, hit and release <kbd>K</kbd>, then while still holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd>, hit <kbd>D</kbd>.

There is no way that I know of to disable the "wrapping" feature, but if you go too far and want to back up, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>), known as `soft_undo`, as many times as needed to go back to where you want to be.

Comment: Soft undo is the correct option. I didn't notice it before. Thanks!